# Connect to database in the middle of the application flow

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to design a Springboot+ Hibernate application which will have the first page as a form which will take in the Database username and password, instead of hardcoding (spring.datasource.username/spring.datasource.password).

So I do not want to connect to the database initially on server startup, but want to do this only once the user enters the correct database username and password. Is this possible and how do I go about it? I searched a lot for this but I am only getting stuff related to SpringSecurity.

Comment: You have only one user of this app ? How if the user disconnect ? What about the second coming user when the db is already connected with the first one? +1 nice post, It's important to understand the goal behind.

Comment: No I have around 20 users. I want them to login using the Database username and password since the Database username and password keeps changing and I can't change the password in the application.properties everytime.

Comment: So, no matter if the 20 users will have the same credential (the same data session) ? or you'll have 20 database pre-registred users ? I ask because it's interresting :)

Comment: All the users are internals :) So yes its the same credentials ..the application is something to prevent the users from logging into the Database everytime :)